# How to Trap Outlook Events from Excel Application

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a workbook that at least 15 people use and update periodically that contains client information with emails within column H3:H1500.  Using the Worksheet_FollowHyperlink event, we can send emails through our Outlook accounts that are pre-written and dependent upon what day of the week an order is requested (M-F, Saturday and Sunday) and the code works just fine to generate messages.  *My main problem is in tracking responses to clients.*  I tried having a sub that recorded date (NOW function) and Environ("username") whenever the hyperlink within column H was selected, but as I have the e-mail sub set to .Display (so people can make any last minute adjustments, if needed) it only records who selected the hyperlink (which, apparently happens a lot on accident when the message is never actually sent).  I had found several threads throughout this forum and others that reference creating a Class module and I implemented one that was used to see if it would work in my code, but by adding it, the entire email sub was rendered useless so I reverted back to the old form. As I am not extremely experienced in VBA (I have gotten this far due to help and trial and error), I realize that some of my choices of code may seem silly, and if there are better ways to do this, I am open to it - I just know that, this sheet works *mostly* for now and I hope it can be improved, if possible.

My current email sub is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
Dim Body1, Body2, Body3 As String
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OlMail As Outlook.MailItem

On Error Resume Next
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set olApp = GetObject(,"Outlook.Application")

Do While olApp.Inspectors.Count = 0
DoEvents

Loop

Set olMail = olApp.Inspectors.Item(1).CurrentItem

With olMail

Body1 = "This is my weekday text"
Body2 = "This is my Saturday text"
Body3 = "This is my Sunday text"

.Subject = "Subject"
.Attachemnts.Add "C:\Path"
.CC = Target.Range.Offset(0,4).Text
.BCC = ""

If Target.Range.Offset(0,5).Text = "No" Then
.Body1
If Target.Range.Offset(0,5).Text = "Yes" Then
.Body2
If Target.Range.Offset(0,5).Text = "Sunday" Then
.Body3

.Display
End With

forward:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
halt:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume forward
End Sub
```

[The above code is in the Excel VBE, the following code is in the Outlook VBE, I should have included that before starting - it is working fine for me right now, so I am not sure why it is not compiling...]

```
Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
Dim objApp As Application

Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
On Error Resume Next
Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
Case "Explorer"
Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
Case "Inspector"
Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
End Select
Set objApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: *My main problem is in tracking responses to clients.*  What does this actually mean?

Comment: I am hoping to be able to track the user and date of who accessed the email hyperlink and actually sent it.  (proceeded from .Display to .Send) That way, I can run a report to accurately track who has been responded to, and who still needs to have a responses sent.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile BTW.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to track the `.Send` unless you actually include that in part of this script.  Once the script terminates, you lose the handle on the `Outlook` application object (and all its children, including your MailItem object).   I can think of a way to maybe do this but it's going to be quite complicated...

Comment: It's fairly simple to detect whether the message has been *sent*, but what I can't figure out is how to determine whether the message was closed without sending.  Without trapping that condition, you'll end up in an infinite loop. I'd suggest using another method than `FollowHyperlink`, since the inadvertent clicks are causing false positives.  **NB** that your `On Error Resume Next` statement is going to cause problems, since it's not actually trapping any errors...

Comment: You certainly have three `IF` statements **without** corresponding `End If`.  That will cause a failure to compile. You can't even execute the code. Make sure you have copied it all in?  Also, the Outlook code you have provided is not called anywhere in your Excel code. It's irrelevant, unless you can revise your Q again to show how it's being used.

Comment: Also, `.Body1`, `.Body2` and `.Body3` are **not** properties of the `olMail` object. These are errors you would probably see if you weren't using the clumsy `Resume Next`...  Perhaps you meant `.Body = Body1`, `.Body = Body2`, etc.?

Comment: You caught me, I neglected to include the "." for all of the .body statements.  Additionally, my code does have the end if, but I missed that when entering it in here.

Comment: What purpose is the Outlook function? It is not called from the other procedure, so it seems irrelevant to this problem.

Comment: An excellent question... I think I created that when I originally was trying to get the email sub to work, but then went a different route...I should not have included it, in hindsight.  Honestly, like I said, I am an extreme novice to VBA and am not entirely sure how things work sometimes, but tinker with them until they work...What was your quite complicated soulution?

Comment: Too complicated to describe here and for free haha. I think I have another idea to brute force it. Give me a few...

Comment: Today's your lucky day :) This was a *really* interesting question and I spent too much time on it, but I think I can give you a good starting point which seems to work.

Comment: Had a chance to try out the solution yet?

Comment: So, I have just tested this, and it definitely looks like it could be what I am hoping to do.  When I placed it in as you directed, I get a compile error from the SendMail code that says cOutlook.OutApp "Not defined". I am seeing if I can get it to work beyond that compile issue. You certainly put a lot of effort into this and I really appreciate all of your help!

Comment: I had made some changes to the code since yesterday, thought I put in the updated version but I might've missed part of it. Let me double-check :)

Comment: OK, revised again below.

Comment: Hmm.  Now it is not throwing any errors but not pre-writing the text I had written and not tracking items sent... I'll keep working and see if there's anything that I can figure out. Thank you, sir!

Comment: You're going to have to put the `.Body` text back in. I took that out when I was developing the answer, since it's not particularly important for the test to see if it works.  Currently, the confirmation that item is sent was only printed in the VBA "Immediate" window. YOu would have to modify to print it on the worksheet or whatever.

Comment: the procedure `m_Send` is what logs the send event. Right now it is just a `Debug.Print` statement. You can modify to print it somewhere else if you'd like.  Or you can change it to `MsgBox "Item was sent by " & Environ("Username") & " at " & Now()` in order to see that it is working.

Comment: Aha.  I did put the text back in for the .Body areas and it was not pre-populating anything (no subject, Cc, or attachments) but I will check again to see if I missed something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to work with events in outlook, from an Excel thread, really really interesting Q and I didn't know if it would be possible.  I think this will get you started.

> I am hoping to be able to track the user and date of who accessed the email hyperlink and actually sent it.

**PROBLEM:** The hyperlink is opening another application (Outlook), over which you don't have full control. And at least from the VBA side, you do NOT have control over the Outlook events.

I thought there may be an easier way to hack around a solution but that was a dead end, you had hinted at class object, so I figured I had an idea that might work... never done this before though, so it's a work in progress.

**To solve this, I settle on an approach that does:**

1. Kills the hyperlinks so that they don't automatically launch Outlook
2. Use the `SelectionChange` event to send the mail via VBA rather than the `FollowHyperlink` event
3. Create a custom event handler class object for an Outlook MailItem which will trap the `_Send` event, which you can then use to log the details of the send.

**Here are the codes/instructions:**

Create a class object called `cMailItem` and put this code inside it:

```
Option Explicit
'MailItem event handler class
Public WithEvents m As Outlook.MailItem

Public Sub Class_initialize()

    Set m = olApp.CreateItem(0)

End Sub

Private Sub m_Send(Cancel As Boolean)

        Debug.Print "Item was sent by " & Environ("Username") & " at " & Now()
        Call ReleaseTrap

End Sub
```

In a *STANDARD* code module (I call this one `HelperFunctions` but the name doesn't matter) put this code, which will set a flag for our `cMailItem` Event Handler class and also contains the function which returns the instance of Outlook Application.

```
Option Explicit
'#################
'NOTE: The TrapEvents should be called when the Forms are initialized
'NOTE: The ReleaseTrap should be called when the Forms are closed
Public olApp As Outlook.Application
Public cMail As New cMailItem
Public TrapFlag As Boolean

Sub TrapEvents()
If Not TrapFlag Then
   Set olApp = GetApplication("Outlook.Application")
   TrapFlag = True
End If
End Sub

Sub ReleaseTrap()
If TrapFlag = True Then
   Set olApp = Nothing
   Set cMail = Nothing
   TrapFlag = False
End If
End Sub

Function GetApplication(Class As String) As Object
'Handles creating/getting the instance of an application class
Dim ret As Object

On Error Resume Next

Set ret = GetObject(, Class)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set ret = CreateObject(Class)
End If

Set GetApplication = ret

On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Now, part of the problem is the way that the hyperlink follow takes precedence over other events. To avoid that, I use some code to "kill" the hyperlinks. They will "link" only to the cell wherein they reside, but they will still contain the text for the email address.

Instead of using the `FollowHyperlink` event, I use the `SelectionChange` event to call another procedure which sends the mail.

In your WORKSHEET module, put the following event handlers AND the `SendMail` procedure:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
'Converts Mailto hyperlinks so that they do NOT
' automatically open Outlook MailItem

    Dim h As Hyperlink

    For Each h In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
        If h.Address Like "mailto:*" Then
            h.ScreenTip = h.Address
            h.Address = ""
            h.SubAddress = h.Range.Address
        End If

    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'Disable Excel events
Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Cells.Count <> 1 Then GoTo EarlyExit
    If Target.Hyperlinks.Count <> 1 Then GoTo EarlyExit

    'Send mail to the specified recipient/etc.
    Call SendMail(Target)

EarlyExit:
'Re-enable events:
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
Private Sub SendMail(Target As Range)

Dim Body1$, Body2$, Body3$
Dim OlMail As Outlook.MailItem
Const OLMAILITEM As Long = 0

'Set our Outlook event trap
Call TrapEvents

'CREATE the mailitem
Set OlMail = cMail.m 

With OlMail

    Body1 = "This is my weekday text"
    Body2 = "This is my Saturday text"
    Body3 = "This is my Sunday text"

    .To = Target.Text
    .Subject = "Subject"
    '.Attachemnts.Add "C:\Path"
    .CC = Target.Offset(0, 4).Text
    .BCC = ""

    .Display
End With


End Sub
```

**NOTE ON REVISED ANSWER**

I revised this from the original solution which used an Outlook Application event handler class, which was limited by the fact that it would trap **ANY** item_send event, this was problematic because multi-tasking users would send false positives.  The revised solution uses an event handler for the `MailItem` object which is created at run-time, and should avoid that pitfall.

**THERE MAY BE OTHER LIMITATIONS**

For example, this method does not really handle "multiple" emails, so if the user clicks one link, and then another, there will only be ONE email that exists and can be tracked. If you need to handle multiple emails, use a public `Collection` of this class object, which I did for [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43941924/1467082).

As I said, this is the first time I've ever attempted to use a `WithEvents` handler between two applications. I've used theme in single-application Add-Ins, etc., but never binding two applications in this manner, so it's uncharted territory for me.